# How to clean Linux and get it back to its original state?

Tags: dependencies, cleanup

Ok, first of all, the question above might be worded wrong so please forgive me if this is the case. So for clarification let me explain;

In the process of troubleshooting something, one tries multiple solutions until they find the right one. What can I do to prevent a failed solution hampering the next correct solution?

For example;
Today I'm trying to get my iPhone 5 working in Kubuntu 16.10 (I need to download photos from it). I do my research and find multiple ways of solving the problem. So I randomly pick a solution that says install so and so package. So I go and do sudo apt install so and so package. CLI says, you need to install 1000!?!? dependencies to make so and so package work. I'm like OK cool, that's a lot of packages, but I think I can handle it. So I go and install them. But then bam, solution 1 crashed and burned. And I'm all like, it ain't no biggie. I can just delete all of those dependencies. So then I do `sudo apt purge <1000 dependencies>`, but then out of nowhere the CLI says I'm only deleting 500 dependencies.

And then I'm all like, wait, what if those 500 dependencies get all huffy and jealous cause in my next attempt at solution 2, CLI says, you need to install 2000 dependencies for so and so version 2 package to work? You know how it is with unmet dependencies, they are never resolved.

Anyways, the whole point of this obnoxious long diatribe is this; how do do I get back to a clean operating system without having to do a complete reinstall?

Today in the process of fixing this iPhone drama, I accidentally deleted Xserver. It's OK, because I got my lovely GUI back, but I really don't want to have to go through another heart attack just to try multiple solutions. So if anyone could enlighten me it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
sudo apt-get purge <somepackage>
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

All of the uneeded dependencies will be removed